# Enabling Stream Management in ejabberd server getting last message repeated

Tags: stream, ejabberd

I have a problem with Stream Management. I have added the following settings in my ejabberd.yml

```
stream_management: true
resume_timeout: 5
resend_on_timeout: true
```

The  function of stream management working fine. i got the all message after resumption of connection. The main issues  is before getting connection resumption, if client send me message in between then i got all in between message two times. How to manage queue on ejabberd server to work fine i.e. (how getting message in  sequence  as send) and avoid getting repeated message.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get reliable delivery without having duplicated message in some situation. When that happens you need to use message id to undupe the messages on the client side.

Comment: Thanks for your reply .i will just look how to handle it.